# Is there a way to embed <iframe> Google Maps into the most current version of DNN (07.02.02) without an iframe module?

Tags: iframe, dotnetnuke

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d43867.046029057456!2d- 112.01569394999997!3d46.59335794999998!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x8837f86ba6483c4e!2sSpring+Meadow+Lake+State+Park!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1396467122025" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

This is the code, not the exact address but either way it will not embed correctly, it embeds and it shows the map, but it is zoomed out and has no coordinates plotted at all or the address of where it is supposed to be pointing at. Any help is appreciated, i need this inside of a tab in DNN so i cant use the iframe module.

Comment: You should just be able to drop it in an HTML module.  Just paste it as HTML instead of using the rich text editor.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, I have already embedded the <iframe> HTML into my tabs inside of my HTML Pro module in DNN, it will show the map just fine, but does not lock onto the coordinates, DNN must be doing something to stop the script but i have no idea...

Comment: Probably.  I used to run a site that had another website IFrame'd into DNN and it did have some quirks.  It worked fine, but after I closed the IFrame, it would mess up the CSS on the DNN menu.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Edit your page and add text/html module to your page with a `<div id="map_canvas"></div>`
- Go to page settings > Advance > Header section and add fpllowing script:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
    <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),//set you long lat here
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

this should work

Comment: You could also use the Module Header or Footer sections on the module to do the javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select HTML Mode in HTML Editor
2. Use "Raw" mode to pervent  tag encoding.
3. Enjoy

Comment: Check your HTML Editor Provider:
yourdomain.com/Host/HTML_Editor_Manager

My setting is: Current Provider: DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider


When editing your text in HTML/Text Module

Select option "Raw text" from bottom right dropdown

select HTML mode in editor and "Raw text Mode"

http://i.piccy.info/i9/9d53d430f5582113a88b4898f2e3d630/1487755611/38080/1121541/html_editor.jpg